# Enabling evolutions on a project, with established schema and data in the DB

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have had a Play Framework 1.x project under development for a few months now. During this time, I've collected some data in the DB, which I can't afford myself to lose.

Now, I need to do changes to the schema, including setting some default data on each of the records collected so far.

I need to apply those changes, and the default data automatically across a few machines, with the ability to roll back the state of the database if needed.

I learned about evolutions quite recently, but I guess they have not been activated, because I can't find them in my project's folders. Is there any way to create the first revision of the evolutions automatically, based on the existing database?

Answer (score 3):

There's no automatic way to do this. You'll need to use a database tool to dump the schema to a file (containing all the SQL necessary to create your database tables, indices, sequences etc. and initial data) and then modify it so that it contains "# --- !Ups" and "# --- !Downs" as described in the [Play! docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/evolutions).

Name this file '1.sql'. Then, in your project root create a directory named 'db/evolutions' and place the file in that directory.

Then run 'play evolutions:markApplied' to tell Play! that your database already up-to-date with the evolution contained in '1.sql'.